# How do I know which drivers to install on an OEM laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, drivers

I have a Toshiba Satellite Model C55t-B5109, and I am looking to do a clean install, via the method of using media creation installation tool to find the product key within the Processor, as many computers have nowadays. The support page with drivers is [here](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200008391) so I am looking to move these to a flash drive and install them with the fresh Windows without all of my preloaded Toshiba programs. 
I need help, I only want the drivers and any control panels that are required, such as for my processor or integrated graphics and such without all the pre-loaded games, start guides, or Norton, and put it in a .zip for me to extract install the programs 1 by 1. Can someone make that for me, or tell me which ones on the page to get, and what version (There is like 2-3 of each). To anyone who does this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Windows, it will try to install all the drivers it needs from Windows Update.

After all updates have been completed (check a couple of times because sometimes you have to install a set then another set become available) and you've rebooted, open up the Device Manager (you can find it by clicking the Windows button then type the name).

Look down the list for any entries that have an exclamation mark in a yellow triangle. Make a note of what they are and download the appropriate driver from the Toshiba site.

It isn't a disaster if you install an extra driver.

Comment: Thank you, but I heard windows automatic install drivers aren't great, and many don't include the control Panel, and wouldnt it not have a network driver to make LAN work to be able to install the other drivers, or does Windows have a generic pre-installed one?

Comment: That can be the case but it will get you working. To be honest, most of the control panels are rubbish and really pretty pointless for W7+ The only one I'd ever use is the one that allows you to associate a programme with built-in/dedicated graphics. If you are concerned, grab the key drivers to a memory stick first. Graphics, network (wired & wireless). But most hardware is covered by generic drivers in WU these days. You might get a performance boost by putting the Toshiba drivers on but equally you might not.

Comment: The problem is, if you look on the site, there is multiple of each, so which one do I do? For example there is 3 Bluetooth driver packages, same version, slightly different file size. Here is the copy-paste: Atheros Bluetooth Filter Driver Package
Posted Date: 2014-04-15 | Version: 2.0.27 | Size: 9.92M
Atheros Bluetooth Filter Driver Package
Posted Date: 2014-05-03 | Version: 2.0.27 | Size: 9.92M
Atheros Bluetooth Filter Driver Package
Posted Date: 2014-03-13 | Version: 2.0.26 | Size: 9.91M

Comment: You are getting hung up on things that are unlikely to matter. Do the install and see what doesn't work. You may never need to install a separate BT driver. If you do, choose the latest - if that doesn't work, choose the next. And while you are doing that write an email to Toshiba asking them what the heck they are playing at.

Comment: I will try :) and thanks for the help, I will update with answered after I test, will try by tomorrow

Comment: Good luck! Let us know.

Comment: I did it, and after the long setup, pretty much all my required drives were installed! I have my Intel Graphics with the control Panel, my Bluetooth, and everything else seems to be plug and play or secret install no user end software drivers. I have to tell you, I was SOOOOO worried. I updated my BIOS because it fixed a problem with not being able to boot USB, and I went into a CSM boot and deleted my Win 8, only to find out I would format it because the drive type was only available in UEFI boot, which I tried and worked like a charm. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: It's a pleasure. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

No need for so much unnecessary work. Just back up your personal data, and use your Windows 8.1 Recovery Boot Drive (you DID create one of those, didn't you?)
and run the handy Reset utility to bring your machine back to its fresh, out of the box condition.

Toshiba laptops specify pressing F12 while powering-on to boot over that thumb drive. You will then see a big blue menu that includes the Reset function. Don't use Refresh.

Once your computer is up and running with its fresh operating system, go into Programs and Features and uninstall the unwanted programs. (I agree that Norton should be on the "dump list")

Some of the included Toshiba utilities are pretty good, so don't do a mass uninstall. Check what each one does first.

I've done this exercise on several Toshiba laptops and it works just dandy. The native Windows uninstaller will do a good job, you don't have to have some "secret recipe killer" 3rd party uninstaller program.

By doing the Refresh recovery, you will automatically get the drivers and other features created by Toshiba, and it will not be necessary to go to their website and hunt them down, and try and figure out which ones to install first, as some drivers and features depend upon others for proper functioning.

BY THE WAY, if your computer is running well now, why not just uninstall the unwanted games, etc. using Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features. You'll save time and a lot of work....

Comment: That's the thing. I DONT want a ouT of the box, crap computer. Even after uninstalling, I see  files were left behind and I like my computer neat. I actually saw my Norton in some hidden folders after uninstalling. I don't even need my product key, it's build right in to my hardware which allows me to reinstall without a problem. I don't mind taking the extra step to reinstall that way, I would prefer it to uninstalling crap and maybe have it left behind in App Data or other hidden folders scattered around. Thanks for the suggestion though, I really apricicate the help, and have a nice day.

Comment: And also,min my computers current state, I uninstalled crapware and have my computer running at BARE minimum, literally just drivers and Google Chrome, along with other non-background tasks, I just wanted a clean start like I do every 6 months or so without having to go through the dread and worry of uninstalling everything